# How can I get only the image src in a wordpress loop

Tags: php, image, wordpress, loops, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive WordPress folio site (www.jasongilmour.co.uk) and I know very little about WP theme development so got really stuck at some of the PHP. I'm looking to make my site truly responsive by loading different images for different devices but can't get the right code...

What I have now is getting the full size images from a post for a maximage2 slideshow.

```
<div id="maximage">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID
            );

            $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                if ( $attachments ) {
                foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
                }
            }

        endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I tried to embed it in a `<picture>` tag and echo out only the src but when I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` it returns the HTML "`ArrayArrayArrayArray`". I also tried putting `echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full', 'src'` but that didn't change the returned HTML.

I don't really understand the WP documentation enough to make it work in a... loop or array I think this is called? So that wasn't much good to me.

This is a pretty important part of my site since I'm using massive images to keep to my design idea and it makes the site very slow before it's cached.

PS

Although I've learned a lot over the past couple of weeks making this, I still don't really understand what I'm doing with PHP... I'm just a graphic design student.

I might also make the theme open source so if anyone is interested in getting a copy let me know.

I also need to sort an issue with mouse hover menus on tablet devices before I'm happy with it but I don't understand what I'm doing there either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the examples here, just substitute in your expression for the ID whereever they ask for it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not as clean as I hoped but it certainly works, the site is a million times faster now. The Javascript simply comments out the unwanted HTML at certain screen sizes so I can get all the image sizes I need meaning the PHP wasn't changed.

```
<script>
document.write("<!--");
if (screen.width <= '400') {document.write(" good -->");}
</script>
<div id="maximage">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            }
        }

    endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
 if (screen.width <= '400') {document.write("<!-- good ");}
</script>
-->

<script>
document.write("<!--");
if ((screen.width >= '401') && (screen.width <= '800')) {document.write(" good -->");}
</script>
<div id="maximage">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            }
        }

    endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
 if ((screen.width >= '401') && (screen.width <= '800')) {document.write("<!-- good ");}
</script>
-->

<script>
document.write("<!--");
if ((screen.width >= '801') && (screen.width <= '1280')) {document.write(" good -->");}
</script>
<div id="maximage">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'large' );
            }
        }

        endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
 if ((screen.width >= '801') && (screen.width <= '1280')) {document.write("<!-- good ");}
</script>
-->

<script>
document.write("<!--");
if (screen.width >= '1281'){document.write(" good -->");}
</script>
<div id="maximage">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => null,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID
        );

        $attachments = get_posts( $args );
            if ( $attachments ) {
            foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
            }
        }

        endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<script>
 if (screen.width >= '1281') {document.write("<!-- good ");}
</script>
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

> but when I use wp_get_attachment_image_src it returns the HTML

That's beacause that function returns an array according to [the source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src), containing image  URL, width and height.

So:

```
list($url, $width, $height) = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
printf('<img src="%s" width="%d" heigt="%d"', $url, $width, $height);

// or vprintf and directly pass the function call...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! I pasted that in instead of the 'echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );' line but it doesn't loop through for each image in the post and I can't make it get the other image sizes. That's the closest I got, I tried a bunch of other stuff but it normally just broke my php. I'm really sorry, I honestly don't understand much of what I'm doing.

Comment: You're querying for attachments of `$post->ID` Are you positive that this post has the number of expected attachments? What does `count($attachments)` suggest?

Comment: Yeah, positive, count($attachments) gives me what I'd expect too. I only managed to get the src of one image an all the posts.

Comment: Here's a link to the zip file for the theme, it's in the single.php file.
[link](http://jasongilmour.co.uk/blast/base.zip)

Comment: Still not looping through for some reason :/